# imagecopymerge get white background instead of black

Tags: php

I need to merge two images together and add text to it. But when the code outputs I get black background. When I remove "imagecopymerge" function I see white background.

```
$firstUrl = '1.jpg';   
$secondUrl = "2.jpg";
$a  = getimagesize ($firstUrl);    

$x = 320;
$y = $a[1]+88;

$image = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $white);     

$first = imagecreatefromjpeg($firstUrl);
$second = imagecreatefromjpeg($secondUrl);

imagecopymerge($image,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,100);
imagecopymerge($image,$second,$a[0]-70,$a[1]+10,0,0, 60, 60,100);    

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 51, 51, 51);
$font = 'a.ttf';
imagettftext($image, 12, 0, 10, $a[1]+30, $text_color, $font, "text");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the width and height of the image you want to insert:

```
imagecopymerge($image,$first,0,0,0,0,imagesx($first),imagesy($first),100);
```

`$x` and `$y` are the dimensions of the final image. If `$first` is smaller than that, then [`imagecopymerge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) fills the missing area with black.

By using [`imagesx()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and [`imagesy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php), you copy the exact area of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line, imagecopymerge($image,$first,0,0,0,0, $x, $y,100); into something like **imagecopymerge($image,$first,100,100,0,0, $x, $y,100);**
Then it should work.